# robots.txt for URL masking

Tags: robots.txt

I have single directory "demo". I've make URL masking on it which is `demo.example.com` and `preview.example.com`.

I want to allow search engine crawling only on `demo.example.com`. I want robots.txt to disallow `preview.example.com` URL.

robots.txt is common for both URLs.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can not specify domains/host names in robots.txt. That would not make sense, because the robots.txt is already “tied” to the domain, simply by its position - domain.foo/robots.txt. You _need_ to serve two different versions of the robots.txt, one for each of your domains. Using some internal rewriting that should be accomplishable somehow.

Comment: @CBroe thank you. How can I serve two different version of robots.txt in single folder? As I mention I have making URL masking and there are only one directory which calling by two different domains

Comment: That depends on what system/setup you are using, and how much control it allows you. “URL Masking” is just a general term, that can mean several different things, and be based on different techniques. You need to find out if you can use your own rewrite rules or sth. similar.

Comment: As you used the tag [tag:.htaccess], does this mean you can use a `.htaccess` file on your host? If yes, did you search for solutions (e.g., with the search term: "different robots.txt .htaccess") / try something?